# asp.net mvc3, c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Is there an easy way to pass an object from my controller to view to controller?

I tried *ViewData["compaignId"]* but that didn't work.

**Controller *"Content"* :**

```
ViewData["CompaignId"] = id;
```

**View *"Content"* :**

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Go To Team Creation", "Team", ViewData["CompaignId"])
</div>
```

**Controller *"Team"*:**

```
public ActionResult Team(long CompaignId)
{
    ....
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use:

**Controller "Content" :**

```
ViewBag.CompaignId = id;
```

**View "Content" :**

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Go To Team Creation", "Team", new 
    { 
        CompaignId = (long)ViewBag.CompaignId 
    })
</div>
```

**Controller "Team":**

```
public ActionResult Team(long CompaignId)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: I would like to send tweet using LinqToTwitter,
 have you any example or documentation
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In general you should use a ViewModel for things like that. But you can use the `ViewBag` too.

```
ViewBag.CompaignId = id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936.aspx)

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues
)
```

And you can pass [anonymous object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) as last parameter

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Go To Team Creation", "Team", new { campaignId = (int)ViewData["CompaignId"] })
</div>
```